# java- validate Map values to be not null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class:

```
    public class SomeClass {

     private Map<Long, Boolean> longToBooleanMap = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

     public Map<Long, Boolean> getLongToBooleanMap () {
        return longToBooleanMap ;
      }

    public void setLongToBooleanMap (Map<Long, Boolean> longToBooleanMap ) {
        this.longToBooleanMap = longToBooleanMap ;
      }
    }
```

I want to be sure that my map will not contain entry with null value. What I tried :

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

 @NotNull
 private Map<Long, Boolean> longToBooleanMap = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();
```

this is validating the Map itself, not the values. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: you need to loop through map and check if any value is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to validate an object with `javax.validation.constraints` the easy way would be creating a method which validates it, returning true if all values are not null and false if there is a null value, then you need to annotate it with `@AssertTrue`, in case is false the validation will not passed.

```
@AssertTrue(message="There is a value which is null")
public boolean hasNotNullValues(){
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Boolean> entry : longToBooleanMap.entrySet()) {
           for (Map.Entry<Long, Boolean> entry : longToBooleanMap.entrySet()) {
            if(null == entry.getValue())
                return false
        }
        return true;
        }
   }
```

---

Otherwise, A way to check you cannot add key-pair with null values would be encapsulating in a method which controlls that, like next:

```
public Map<Long, Boolean> putLongToBooleanMap (Long key, Boolean value) {
        if(value != null)
            longToBooleanMap.put(key, value);
        else
          //TODO do what you want (for example: throw an exception..)
 }
```

Then if you are looking to be sure is not possible to add a map with nulls, you could delete your getter method  and setter methods: `getLongToBooleanMap` and `setLongToBooleanMap`. If you choose to do that, you would need to create other util methods like remove `key-value`.

Answer (score -1):

Additionaly to [Pau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162456/java-validate-map-values-to-be-not-null/41162549#41162549), and You really want to use HashMap, You can override Your map like this (or create easily a separated class):

```
    final Map<Long, Boolean> longToBooleanMap = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean put(Long key, Boolean value) {
            if(value != null) {
                return super.put(key, value);
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException("This map cannot contain null values");
            }
        }

        /*
         * TODO: Overwrite methods: putAll, replace, replaceAll, ...
         */

    };
```

But please note You need to overwrite many methods which adds items into the map. Only mentioning some of them: put, putAll, putIfAbsent, replace, replaceAll, merge.

Answer (score -2):

You can use ConcurrentHashMap. This implementation does not allow to have null key and null values.